# Unexpected behavior in printing a char array in C

Tags: c

I recently encountered an interesting issue in a piece of code I had to write. Although I fixed the issue using a different approach to my original one, I would like to see if anybody has any idea as to why the original didn't work. Here are the condensed code snippets.

**Original code:**

```
int i, j, k;
for (i=0; i!=10, (result = fgets(newline, 1024, stream))!=NULL; i++)
{
    result = strtok(newline, " ");
    for (j=0; j!=x; j++) {
        for (k=0; k!=y; k++) {
            score_matrix[i][j][k] = result;
             printf("%d ", atoi(score_matrix[i][j][k]));
            result = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
     printf("\n");
}
```

In the code above, `stream' is a CSV file. Anyway, the code above prints out the CSV file as it is supposed to be:

```
19 17 20 18 
9 6 10 9 
12 11 10 16 
3 7 9 10 
0 5 8 6 
15 13 15 15 
20 18 18 16 
17 19 19 18 
13 15 14 12 
10 13 18 15
```

However, when I take the *same exact code as above* but only remove a few irrelevant lines:

```
int i, j, k;
for (i=0; i!=10; i++) {
    for (j=0; j!=x; j++) {
        for (k=0; k!=y; k++) {
            printf("%d ", atoi(score_matrix[i][j][k]));
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

It prints out:

```
10 13 18 15 
10 0 3 8 
10 13 18 15 
10 0 3 18 
10 0 3 18 
10 13 18 15 
10 13 18 15 
10 13 18 15 
10 13 18 15 
10 13 18 15
```

Which is very wrong.
**Fixed code** (which does nothing more than convert the matrix to `int`, and removes the `atoi`):

```
int i, j, k;
for (i=0; i!=10, (result = fgets(newline, 1024, stream))!=NULL; i++)
{
    result = strtok(newline, " ");
    for (j=0; j!=x; j++) {
        for (k=0; k!=y; k++) {
            score_matrix[i][j][k] = atoi(result);
            printf("%d ", score_matrix[i][j][k]);
            result = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

and

```
int i, j, k;
for (i=0; i!=10; i++) {
    for (j=0; j!=x; j++) {
        for (k=0; k!=y; k++) {
            printf("%d ", score_matrix[i][j][k]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

now both print the right thing:

```
19 17 20 18 
9 6 10 9 
12 11 10 16 
3 7 9 10 
0 5 8 6 
15 13 15 15 
20 18 18 16 
17 19 19 18 
13 15 14 12 
10 13 18 15
```

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm very curious as to why this is happening.

EDIT:

- `x` --> passed by argument. In this case it's 2.
- `score_matrix` --> In bad code is `char* score_matrix[10][x][y];`, in good it's `int score_matrix[10][x][y];`
- `newline` --> `char newline[1024];`
- `result` --> `char* result;`
- Also, result has been validated with printf statements.

Comment: check the array bounds of `score_matrix` carefully, remembering that each index is zero based.

Comment: How are `score_matrix`, `newline` and `x` declared ?

Comment: ... and how is `x` calculated ?

Comment: validate `result` of `strtok`

Comment: The first snippet does *not* "work" as you think. You're sending offsets into the same `newline` buffer with each outer iteration, obliterating the validity of the prior enumerations by overwriting their data. Removing the output from the loop and repeating it immediately afterward *without* the stream extraction will demonstrate this. Further, I can all-but-guarantee you if you dump the *address* for each string you'll find the first "slab" always has the same address (that of `newline`), further evidence that your matrix is in anything-but the good-state you think it is.

Comment: `result = strtok(NULL, " ");` what does it mean??

Comment: @MichaelWalz, please see EDIT for the answers. @SGG, it's required to be called as such to get the next token. See `strtok` man page.

Comment: @wyas great, now read my comment and understand why reusing the same line buffer and storing offsets within it (which is all `strotok` does; return terminated substrings in the provided buffer) is *wrong*. It is no coincidence those rows seem to be reporting the same data as the *last* row. If you need the data as `int` anyway, just use the "fixed" version and avoid what will only be solvable with dynamic allocation (and later dynamic cleanup).

Comment: @WhozCraig I think if I follow. Thanks. If you would like to write the answer rather than just comment, I'll be more than happy to approve it.

Comment: "Undefined behavior" -- I don't think you understand what those words mean. They definitely don't mean that your program didn't do what you expect it to do. In fact, "undefined behavior" is not any sort of concrete behavior at all -- it means that the C standard does not define how implementations must behave.

Comment: @JimBalter fixed, maybe? I'm aware it isn't undefined, I just didn't know what other word to call it from my end.

Comment: Unexpected behavior. Your edit ("strange") is fine; thanks for changing it.

Comment: @JimBalter I changed it to unexpected. I think it's a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repeated use of the same row-buffer is wrong. The first sample's output is lulling you into a false sense of success when in reality it is anything-but-correct. Modifying the loop to dump the address of the token extracted and being saved will show evidence of this:

```
score_matrix[i][j][k] = result;
printf("%p ", result);
result = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

You will see many of your tokens in the output cube are sharing the same buffer addresses, which of course is because you're passing the same line buffer `newline` for each tokenization, and in the process obliterating the content in any prior loops.

If you want to store actual `char *` you can, but unless you *have to*, **don't**. Instead do what one of your fixed versions does: convert to `int` and store the `int` as the matrix value. Otherwise you'll need something like this for load:

```
int i, j, k;
for (i=0; i!=10, (result = fgets(newline, 1024, stream))!=NULL; i++)
{
    result = strtok(newline, " ");
    for (j=0; j!=x; j++) {
        for (k=0; k!=y; k++) {
            score_matrix[i][j][k] = strdup(result); // NOTE: POSIX strdup() function
            printf("%d ", atoi(score_matrix[i][j][k]));
            result = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
     printf("\n");
}
```

Which will later require a hella-cleanup for all those dynamic allocations. You *could* make a single mondo-allocation that loads the entire file into memory as a single dynamic char buffer and considerably alter your parsing loops, but I advise that even less than I advise the single-token dynamic allocation approach.

Comment: @wyas glad it helped. Seriously. use the `int` solution if you have any say in the matter (and <cough> check your return values from your lib-calls before using them =P)

Comment: `int` solution is there to stay, but I was just curious as to why the heck this all went downhill with `char`s. Glad to know C is as dangerous as always :)